# Use the result of a select as a field name in a view

Tags: mysql

It is possible in mysql create a view that use the column of a table plus the result of another for explain data?
I explain what I mean with an example.

Table 1
[image: Table1]

Table 2
[image: Table2]

Table 3
[image: table3]

I want to select the record of table 2 and use in addition of record of table 1 and insert the data of table 3, like this creating a view that update if i adding row to any table.

[image]

the number on the column is num from table3 from id1 table1 and id2 from table2

Comment: PIVOT is not implemented in MySQL.

Comment: Not with you, views don't update when you run them they will fetch current data.

Comment: And with a sql query?